# How would one motivate/know to introduce the Dirichlet character in the formula for the number of lattice points on a circle of radius $\sqrt N$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, proof-explanation, multiplicative-function, dirichlet-character

Grant's masterful video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NaL_Cb42WyY&ab_channel=3Blue1Brown ("Pi hiding in prime regularities") describes a way of computing $\pi$ that ultimately leads us to the development of Dirichlet characters, and more generally the beginnings of analytic and algebraic number theory. I find the video to be mostly straightforward (brilliant, but not to an eye-watering degree), at least until [minute 20:44](https://youtu.be/NaL_Cb42WyY?t=1244).

There, in a stroke of genius so immense that I can only stare in wonder, we are introduced to a deceptively simple function $\chi$, that ends up giving us a very illuminating form of describing the number of lattice points on a circle of radius $\sqrt N$.

My inquiry is this: let's say I was trying to come up with this formula for $\pi$ on my own. I play around with squares, finding Fermat's Christmas theorem, and its relation to factorization in the Gaussian integers. And I find the preliminary formula for $\#_N :=$ the number of lattice points on a circle of radius $\sqrt N$, namely: breaking down $N$ into prime factors $p^e$ (prime $p$, exponent $e$) and building the desired quantity $\#_N$ by multiplying by [$1$ if $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ and $e$ is even], [$0$ if $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$ and $e$ is odd], and [$(e+1)$ if $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$] for each prime factor $p$, and finally multiplying by $4$.

**Is there then some kind of technique, general philosophy/problem-solving strategy, or thought process I could go through to realize that I could define this function $\chi$ (multiplicative, cyclic) that would simplify this formula into something more illuminating/less "awkward"?** I mean, writing it out in this form involving sums $\chi(p^0) + \chi(p^1) + \ldots + \chi(p^e)$ at first looks so much more complicated, but is actually so much simpler, I just don't know how someone would be able to see past the "complicated" to the "simpler" a priori.

It all seems so...magical and almost coincidental that such a manipulation could be pulled off.

One approach to answering this question would be to imagine you were writing an introductory textbook to the subject, and wanted to insert this problem in the text. What topics/problems would you write about before this one so as to make this problem and its solution appear in a "more natural" context?

Comment: general response (not specific to your question): math has been going on for a long, long time. much more would have been done by now if it was easier

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: when dealing with a function $f(n)$ that is multiplicative/related to factorization, it is standard (once one has experience in this area!) to look at the functions $g(n)$ and $h(n)$ that satisfy $h(n) = \sum_{d\mid n} f(d)$ and $f(n) = \sum_{d\mid n} g(d)$ (both sums are over positive integers $d$ that divide $n$).

In this context, $\#_N = \sum_{d\mid n} \chi(d)$, which motivates looking at the function $\chi$.

Comment: Are there standard problems/examples that a typical person would go through to "build experience in the area" to look for such $g$ and $h$?

Comment: (1) There's actually no need to "look for them"—there is a (simple in hindsight) algorithm for constructing them. If $f$ is multiplicative then so are $g$ and $h$, and so it suffices to construct their values on prime powers; try a few examples and you'll see that that's as simple as multiplying/dividing a polynomial by $1-x$. (2) Two classical results are the asymptotic formulas for $\sum_{n\le x} \tau(n)$, where $\tau(n)$ is the number of divisors of $n$, and $\sum_{n\le x} \frac{\phi(n)}n$, where $\phi$ is the Euler totient function; both proofs use examples of this technique.

Comment: I see now that having seen the "identity" $\sum_{n\leq x} \sum_{d|n} 1 = \sum_{d \leq x} 1\cdot \lfloor \frac xd\rfloor$ which can easily generalize by replacing $1$ by say $f(d)$, the problem $\sum_{n\leq x} \#_n$ instantly reminds one of the "identity". However, why would one want to look at $\sum_{n\leq x} \tau (n)$? Only given that $\tau(n)$ counts the divisors of $n$, I definitely would not think to care about summing $\tau$ over $n$...

Comment: @D.R. : In fact, there is a lot of similarity between the problem of computing $\sum_{n\leqslant t} r(n)$ (I'm using the more traditional notation $r(n)$ for what has been called $\#_n$ in the discussion here) and $\sum_{n\leqslant t} \tau(n)$. 

The latter sum counts the number of lattice points in the first quadrant below the hyperbola $xy = t$ exactly analogous to how the former counts the number of lattice points contained in a circle of radius $t$ centered at the origin. 

The analogy is quite deep, and progress on these problems go hand in hand. Look up the Dirichlet divisor problem.